# Expanding accordion based on anchor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to expand Bootstrap accordion based on an URL anchor?

For example if I load the page with the following URL: **/mypage#headingOne**  I'm using PHP but I understand that none of the URL part after # is passed via server. Perhaps this could be done via JS?..

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    Accordion Item #1
</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
    Accordion Item #2
</button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to research exactly what `/mypage#headingOne` will do. The `#` part is passed and will cause the page to position onto a page link with that name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I go to anchor and open a Bootstrap accordion at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324219/how-can-i-go-to-anchor-and-open-a-bootstrap-accordion-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I come to the page with accordion from another page and I don't use jQuery in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure js implement without jQuery [live demo](https://bluehua.org/demo/bs5-accordion/#headingThree). you could place the code below at bottom of your html body.

```js
(function() {
    // change location hash when toggle a accordion item.
    document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button').forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location.hash = '#' + this.parentNode.id;
        });
    });
    if (!window.location.hash) return;
    // show accordion item based on location hash.
    let act = document.querySelector(window.location.hash)
    if (act) {
        let btn = act.querySelector('.accordion-button');
        if (btn && !btn.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.collapse.show')) {
            btn.click();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant solution! Thanks.